# What are the techniques for Quick Authentication to the XERO API?

Tags: php, oauth, openssl

How can an application check if the user has the correct key? certificate and validate those requirements against those in the [xero api](http://blog.xero.com/developer/)? my current algorithm only checks the accessibility of what is required in-order to make an initial connection to the api but doesn't necessarily check that information is valid.

```
//check for files/keys before running xero
function provideXeroConnection($request = 'xml'){
    //validate everything is inplace
    if(validateXeroAuth()){
        //if it is then bubble the object up to (XeroAc & JSONEngine or XMLEngine)
        return new Xero(XeroAuths::getSetting('xero_consumer'), XeroAuths::getSetting('xero_secret'), XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH, XERO_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, $request );
    } else return false;
/*
* @TODO validate xero authentication
*/
function validateXeroAuth(){
    $xero_key = XeroAuths::getSetting('xero_consumer');
    $xero_secret = XeroAuths::getSetting('xero_secret');
    if(file_exists(XERO_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH) && file_exists(XERO_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)){
        if(validateValue($xero_key) && validateValue($xero_secret)){
            return true; //feature not completely implemented @TODO
        } else return false;
    } else return false;
}
//validate the value for xero
function validateValue($value){
    if(isset($value)){
        if(!is_null($value)){
            if(!empty($value)){
                return true;
            } else return false;
        } else return false;
    } else return false;
}
```

The script in use is opensource and is available at github [here](https://github.com/XeroAPI/PHP-Xero). I've also read the example implementation of the script [here](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroOAuth-PHP). But I haven't really found anything for a quick authentication.

The reason I'm asking this.. is I'd much rather have my users keys and certificates authenticated in a couple of seconds rather than minutes (give and take how many invoices or contact information has to be recieved). Any help on this issue would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is to do a GET Organisation call - if that fails with a 401, you know you have done something wrong.

The long answer is: are you sure you should be using a private API application if you are getting users to authenticate? There are other application types that may be better suited to this scenario (I've made some assumptions so I may be wrong). This might help: [API Application type guide](http://developer.xero.com/getting-started/api-application-types/).

Comment: Hi Ronan, just curious about your comment "are you sure..." we are currently developing a private app to ship out to customers that will query for their address details. Does this pose a security risk as we will be giving them our certificate along with the app? End users are not required to authenticate themselves against a xero user in our organisation.